# Javascript for setting intervals

Tags: javascript, audio, intervals

I have a mp3 file that I am repeating from point A to point B. I set intervals for the start and end time but when I hit pause, it pauses until the function repeats itself. How do I get the Javascript to pause and fully stop the function?

```
var audio = document.getElementById('testPlayer');
setInterval(function play1(){
    audio.currentTime = 7;
    audio.play();
    int = setInterval(function() {
        if (audio.currentTime > 100) {
            audio.pause();
            clearInterval(int);
        }
    }, 10);
}, 7000);
function pause(){
    audio.pause();
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Consider just binding an event handler instead of using `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get the Javascript to pause and fully stop the function?

Don't use `setInterval`. There are a bunch of events you can use that `<audio>` will trigger.

A simple loop can be made using the `timeupdate` event.

```js
document.querySelector('audio').addEventListener('timeupdate', function (e) {
  if (e.target.currentTime > 6) {
    e.target.currentTime = 0;
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<audio src="http://167.88.156.219/phc/2016/04/30/phc_20160430_128.mp3" controls autoplay></audio>
```

<sub>I have tested this only in chrome, so I will leave cross-browser implementation as an exercise for the reader</sub>

Comment: How would you get the song to start at 9 seconds and end at 13?

Comment: @EliTownsend, i'd change the code to use a different set of comparisons.

Comment: @EliTownsend, although you should also consider just cropping the audio file to play only what you want, and then using the `loop` attribute on the `<audio>` element. It's much simpler that way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign an interval to a variable in order to clear it.

Try adding this:

```
var play1interval = setInterval(function play1(){
  ...
  if (audio.currentTime > 100) {
        audio.pause();
        clearInterval(int);
        clearInterval(play1interval);
    }
  }, 10);
}, 7000);
```

In addition, you can tell an interval to reference a function, rather than having to add it in directly.

```
function play1(){
    ...
}

function interval(){
    var int = setInterval(play1, 10);
}

var play1interval = setInterval(interval, 7000);
```

Which isn't necessary, just makes things easier to read.

Comment: So the code should look like this?
var audio = document.getElementById('testPlayer');
var play1interval = setInterval(function play1(){
   audio.currentTime = 7;
    audio.play();
  if (audio.currentTime > 100) {
        audio.pause();
        clearInterval(int);
        clearInterval(play1interval);
    }
  }, 10);
}, 7000);